# Flash +remove via AMFPHP +internet explorer 8 + live

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer-8, amfphp

For the life of me I cannot figure this one out.
OK, here goes.
I have a Facebook game on a live server which works great with Chrome, FF and internet explorer 9+10
but does not work on internet explorer 8.
I use AMFPHP and receive all data for flash game. Another point is ie8 it does work on my local server- but again not on the live server, while all the other browsers and versions do work on the live server.

I did notice that ie8 is rather slow when loading flash.
I have tried other computers as well and it only an ie 8 issue on a live server.
ANY ideas? 
THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works locally but not on your live server, it sounds like you have aserver problem rather than a ie8 problem.
see
http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/troubleshooting-and-debugging-your-project/ 
(getting information about PHP errors in particular)

also
http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/using-a-packet-sniffer/ 
could be of use to see what is going on with ie8

Comment: Thanks for the lead...it turns out - header issues...so I just added header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); as suggested in an answer here at Stackoverflow..worked like a charm...